# Do security rules need to be defined for every subcollections explicitly?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Consider the example from Firebase docs

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /cities/{city} {
      allow read, write: if <condition>;

        // Explicitly define rules for the 'landmarks' subcollection
        match /landmarks/{landmark} {
          allow read, write: if <condition>;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Here the *landmarks* subcollection has explicit security rules. Let's assume I have other subcollections under *cities*. If the rules I want for them are the same as those for *cities* do I need to define them as separate blocks just like *landmarks* ? Or  I can change `/cities/{city}` to `/cities/{city=**}` ?

Which would be the best approach ? Thank you for your time.

Comment: yes,you have to define explicitly

Comment: Any reference for that or is that inferred from the guides implicitly :P ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from you'r question ,i think you have two sub collections,landmarks and capitals;So you need different rule for sub collection 'landmarks'.To achieve this you have to explicitly define each  sub collections security rule.

your rule should be some thing like this,

```
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
match /cities/{city} {
  allow read, write: if <condition>;

    // Explicitly define rules for the 'landmarks' subcollection
    match /landmarks/{landmark} {
      allow read, write: if <condition>;
    }

 // Explicitly define rules for the 'capital' subcollection
    match /capital/{capitals} {
      allow read, write: if <condition>;
    }
}
}
}
```

if you write a rule like this

```
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
match /cities/{city=**} {
  allow read, write;
}
}
 }
```

this rule will apply for every sub collections in the cities collection,even if you are write rule explicitly for some sub collection.

Comment: Edit your answer because you  said two subcollections "cities and landmarks". It should be "capitals and landmarks" as per your example. Will accept as answer then as it seems to be the correct one.